# "Enter/Return" with, or without "Fn"

Tags: macos, snow-leopard, keyboard

Does Mac OS X, and any Mac application, handles <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> differently from <kbd>Enter</kbd>?
As optional question, does any application handles <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>Return</kbd> differently from <kbd>Return</kbd>?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess since <kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>return</kbd> equals <kbd>enter</kbd>, the <kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>enter</kbd>-combination would equal <kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>return</kbd> which does not make much sense, so my vote is: no, there is no app that can receive this combo.

To prove, you'll need to read the key codes sent from keyboard to the system when it´s pressed (ie. [Full Key Codes](https://softwares.bajram.com/full_key_codes/) could do this for you)  - since I don´t have a keyboard with a physical <kbd>enter</kbd> I unfortunately can´t do that.

Comment: I apologize. I have the standard keyboard, which uses two different symbol for the Enter/Return key (one of those symbols is "⌅", the Unicode Projective character); it seems I said _Enter_ when I should have said _Return_.

Comment: Well fn+enter will probably do nothing while fn+return==enter does make a difference. In iTunes, for example, pressing enter on a highlited song will let you change a its name, while return will start playing it. In fact, there are many other apps who recognize this difference, maybe we don´t need to list them all? ;-)

Comment: Sorry to revive this really old question & answer, but is the “Enter” key that is present on the full size keyboard on the numeric keypad an actual “enter” key, or is it the same as the return key on a Mac? if the former is true, then does pressing fn-enter do the same thing as the return key?

Comment: @user3052786 Yes, those two keys are indeed different; while `fn`+`↩` is equal to `⌅`, `fn`+`⌅` is however *not equal* to `↩`. Note that in many applications, both keys produce identical results when pressed.

Comment: Ah I see. I guess there wouldn’t be any reason to use `fn`+`⌅` instead of return. Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 3):

> Does any application handle <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>Return</kbd> differently from <kbd>Return</kbd>?

Yes!  In iTunes 10.5, <kbd>Return</kbd> will make a highlighted song start playing but <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>Return</kbd> will allow you to rename the song.  This was revealed to me at [How can I rename a song in iTunes with a keyboard shortcut?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/28877/how-can-i-rename-a-song-in-itunes-with-a-keyboard-shortcut/28881#28881)

Answer (score 2):

This is not hard to find out.

Open vim and enter insert mode

( Note: I just hit 'j' several times to move the cursor.  Why must I live like this?  Vim mode! Just did it again.)

Hit control-v

Hit your keystroke combo

Observe the char printed

repeat

check if printed char is different

if yes then they are different

if no , such as `<Tab> and <Shift-Tab>` on the console, then they are not different.

EDIT:  Some background:

> **`CTRL-V`**
>
> Insert next non-digit literally. For special keys, the terminal code is inserted.  It's also possible to enter the decimal, octal or hexadecimal value of a character
>
> `i_CTRL-V_digit`.
>
> The characters typed right after `CTRL-V` are not considered for mapping.
>
> `{Vi: no decimal byte entry}`
>
> Note: When `CTRL-V` is mapped (e.g., to paste text) you can often use `CTRL-Q` instead
>
> `i_CTRL-Q`.

I tried this in my terminal.

<kbd>Control</kbd><kbd>V</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd> gave me `^M`

<kbd>Control</kbd><kbd>V</kbd><kbd>Fn</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd> gave me `^C`

So vim sees the two as different. They send different codes.

Comment: Heh, "not hard." For the uninitiated, as I was until googling this through, I'll add some starting steps: Launch Terminal, type `vim` and *Return*, type `i`. Now you're in insert mode. After that, however, I have no idea. *Control-v* doesn't appear to do anything, and *Return* appears to enter a carriage return while *Enter* does nothing.

Comment: Yikes.  You are correct.  Editing.

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>Return</kbd> is also recognized in Finder as the same way as iTunes. 
in fact, this combination is like if you do one click on a selected item to rename it. in Windows world, it is like <kbd>F2</kbd> key.

Comment: In Finder, Enter, Return, fn + Enter, and fn + Return have all the same effect: rename the currently selected item.