# How can I rename a song in iTunes with a keyboard shortcut?

Tags: itunes, snow-leopard, keyboard

I can hit the up and down arrows to navigate a playlist in iTunes 10.5 but hitting F2 doesn't allow me to rename a song.  I have to grab the mouse and do a finicky click, wait, click to highlight the song and then rename it.  Can I just assign F2 to this?  Or can I use an existing keyboard shortcut?

Incidentally, I know I can hit Command-I, and then Command-2, tab to Name, change the name, and hit Return, but this sub-optimal.

Bonus points if you can explain how I would assign such a shortcut to highlight the Genre of a song, which is my more common use case (long story).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

<kbd>fn</kbd> + <kbd>return</kbd> works while navigating with the up and down keys.
Edit the song, then press return again to submit changes.

For the other columns just press <kbd>tab</kbd> to reach the desired column.

Comment: For keyboards without a `fn` key, use the `enter` key from the numeric keypad (`fn`+`return` is often equivalent to the keypad `enter`). Also ⌘+`return` seems to work for this purpose in iTunes 10.5 (probably on either type of keyboard).

Comment: @ChrisJohnsen everything you say here is true.  I'll just use the Enter key on my numeric keypad since it's only one button to press.  Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

- Press <kbd>↑ Up</kbd> or <kbd>↓ Down</kbd> to go to the track in iTunes.
- Press <kbd>⌘ cmd</kbd> + <kbd>↩ return</kbd>.

  [image: Editing Track Name]

  The track name will now highlight and become ready to edit
- Enter the text of the title.

  [image: Typing New Track Name]
- Press <kbd>↩ return</kbd> to commit the renaming of the track.

  [image: Committed rename]

I made a page of this (with pictures) at: http://sites.google.com/site/chrislent/home/rename-a-track-in-itunes-from-the-keyboard

See [Apple KB Article PH12110](http://support.apple.com/kb/PH12110) for an exhaustive list of keyboard shortcuts.